# Incompatible types in initialization?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, double

Why am I getting "incompatible types in initialization" in the following code?

```
NSString *latString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"-44.4349773"];
    NSString *lngString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"-33.2779787"];
    double latDouble = [latString doubleValue];
    double lngDouble = [lngString doubleValue];
    double roundDouble = 0;
    NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber;
    if(latDouble == 0 && lngDouble == 0) {
        NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber = 0;
    }else{
double tempDble = [self calcDiffDistance:latDouble withPostLng:lngDouble ]; <-- incompatible types...
NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:tempDble];



-(double)calcDiffDistance:(double )postLat withPostLng:(double )lon1 {

NSLog(@"beginning CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
CLLocationDegrees lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");

NSLog(@"beginning location1 in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:postLat longitude:lon1];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-44.4343 longitude:-34.977];
NSLog(@"finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");


NSLog(@"beginning location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
double target = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
//int myInt = (int)ceil(target);
target = target/1609.334;
[location1 release];
[location2 release];
NSLog(@"finsished location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts");

return target;
```

}

.h code ////////////////////////////////

```
                                                      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "PostTableCustomCellController.h"
    #import "LoadMoreResultsTableViewCell.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #import "CLController.h"
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


    @class PostDetailViewController;

    @interface TransactionsTableViewController : UITableViewController <CLControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
        IBOutlet UITableView *transactionsTableView;
        NSMutableArray *postsArray;
        PostDetailViewController *postDetailViewController;
        UITableView *transTableView;
        Boolean *isFetchingData;
        int *webServiceAllCount;
        NSCalendar *calendar;
        NSTimer *minuteTimer;
        NSTimer *regionsTimer;
        Boolean *blockRefresh;
        CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;
    @property Boolean *blockRefresh;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) Boolean *isFetchingData;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) LoadMoreResultsTableViewCell *loadMoreResultsCell;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *minuteTimer;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *regionsTimer;


    -(double)calcDiffDistance:(double )postLat withPostLng:(double )lon1;
    - (NSString *)dateDiff:(NSString *)origDate;
    - (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer;
    - (void)updateRegions;
    -(void)newLocationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
    -(void)newError:(NSString *)text;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *transTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *postsArray;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) PostDetailViewController *postDetailViewController;

    @end
```

Comment: it may help to know at which line of code do you get the error... and piu the .h code too, pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess w/o seeing the context within which that code is compiled is that you aren't importing the header file that declares the method `calcDiffDistance:withPostLng:`.

Also, an instance variabel of type `int*` is almost assuredly not what you meant;  do you really want a pointer to an `int`?!

This method name is a bit rough, too:

```
-(double)calcDiffDistance:(double )postLat withPostLng:(double )lon1 {
```

How about something like this:

```
-(double)calculateDistanceFromLatitude:(double)lat longitude:(double)long
```

?

Comment: or better yet, just use the built-in distance calculation stuff in CoreLocation, or at the very least: `-(double)distanceFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;`.

Comment: What Dave said;  I'm not familiar w/the CL APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Pls check the data type of the variables `latDouble` and `lngDouble`. It has to be `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing here `latDouble` and `lngDouble` in `calcDiffDistance` method.And type for these argument does not match with method argument types.see the declration statement.

type for `latDouble` and `lngDouble` must be `double`.

Answer (score 0):

@jgervin: the good new is that i i tried your code in my project at it works, with no error at all...

that's the report in my debugger console:

[2745:207] beginning CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] beginning location1 in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] beginning location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] finsished location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts
[2745:207] *_*_:79893040

i just added your code:

```
-(double)calcDiffDistance:(double )postLat withPostLng:(double )lon1 {

    NSLog(@"beginning CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
//  CLLocationDegrees lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;  // not used
//  CLLocationDegrees lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude; // not used
    NSLog(@"finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");

    NSLog(@"beginning location1 in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:postLat longitude:lon1];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-44.4343 longitude:-34.977];
    NSLog(@"finsished CLLocationDegrees in calcDiff in UsersPosts");


    NSLog(@"beginning location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts");
    double target = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
    //int myInt = (int)ceil(target);
    target = target/1609.334;
    [location1 release];
    [location2 release];
    NSLog(@"finsished location release in calcDiff in UsersPosts");

    return target;
}
```

calling this from somewhere in my code:

```
NSString *latString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"-44.4349773"];
NSString *lngString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"-33.2779787"];
    double latDouble = [latString doubleValue];
    double lngDouble = [lngString doubleValue];
    double roundDouble = 0; // not used
    NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber; // not used
    if(latDouble == 0 && lngDouble == 0) {
        NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber = 0; // not used
    }else{
        double tempDble = [self calcDiffDistance:latDouble withPostLng:lngDouble ]; //
        NSNumber *mylngDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:tempDble];
        NSLog(@"____:%d", mylngDoubleNumber);
    }
```

with this in .h file:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> //
```

and:

```
-(double)calcDiffDistance:(double )postLat withPostLng:(double )lon1;
```

so your compiler error is to search somewhere else, not a declaration method error
the bad new is that i don't know where...

and... your method return different (unexpected) values every time ... like here:

_*_*:100906736

_*_*:100786912

_*_*:79891648

...

ps

i guess you imported the right framework "CoreLocation.framework" in your project, of course...